# отправка вк боту python фото

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Необходимо сделать vk-бота,написанного на Python, который ищет похожие лица, поиск лица начинается с отправки боту фотографии.

Помогите, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пользователь может отправить фото боту в ЛС (то есть, в сообщения сообщества) или в любую беседу с его участием (не забудьте про права на чтение или упоминайте бота с помощью "@").

После этого ВК отправит Вам [событие](https://vk.com/dev/groups_events) `message_new`.

Фотографии будут в списке `attachments`, чтобы получить первое фото из списка:

```py
event.object['attachments'][0]
```

В полученном объекте будет много [полей](https://vk.com/dev/objects/attachments_m), Вам необходимо [`photo`](https://vk.com/dev/objects/photo), в нём будет вся нужная информация, в том числе ссылки на фото в разных качествах.

Чтобы получить ссылку на самое высокое разрешение:

```py
photo['sizes'][-1]['url']
```

**UPD:**
Готовый бот ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶:

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import requests
import io

import settings  # В этом файле у меня токены


while True:
    vkSession = VkApi(token=settings.access_token)
    longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkSession, settings.group_id)
    vk = vkSession.get_api()

    try:
        for event in longPoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                atchs = event.object['attachments']

                if atchs:
                    for atch in atchs:
                        if atch['type'] == 'photo':
                            photo = atch['photo']

                            url = photo['sizes'][-1]['url']
                            print(url)
                            img = requests.get(url).content
                            f = io.BytesIO(img)

    except Exception:
        pass
```

В `f` находится "file-like" объект фотографии, в таком виде его можно передавать на обработку какой-либо функции.

*P. S.: Да простят меня боги за использование конструкции* `while True: try-except`*, но на этот шаг меня вынудил сам ВК. Я имею своего бота и по статистике, ВК примерно раз в день возвращает* `500: Internal Server Error` *или просто не отвечает на longPoll и соединение обрывается. Такие вот дела* ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95181/discussion-on-answer-by-nomnoms12----python-).